# Flutter - change TextFormField background when in active mode (Typing)

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

I want to achieve this.

[image]

While a text form field is inactive, its background, fill color will be grey. But when I am typing or it is in active mode, its background color will be white.

How to achieve this behavior?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-managing-form-input-focus/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through some tests, I have finalized the correct answer. The above answer is good. The first one has a problem. **Focus Node variable must be inside the state class so that it can preserve its state**.

```
class _GlobalTextFormFieldState extends State<GlobalTextFormField> {
  late FocusNode focusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    focusNode = FocusNode();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      focusNode: focusNode,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```dart
class CustomTextFiled extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTextFiled({
    Key? key,
    this.focusNode,
    required this.fillColor,
    required this.focusColor,
    // add whaterver properties that your textfield needs. like controller and ..
  }) : super(key: key);

  final FocusNode? focusNode;
  final Color focusColor;
  final Color fillColor;

  @override
  _CustomTextFiledState createState() => _CustomTextFiledState();
}

class _CustomTextFiledState extends State<CustomTextFiled> {
  late FocusNode focusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    focusNode = widget.focusNode ?? FocusNode();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      focusNode: focusNode,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: focusNode.hasFocus ? widget.focusColor : widget.fillColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for textformfield inside bottom sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FocusNode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) with listener.

```dart
  late final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode()
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    
 ....
  TextField(
    focusNode: focusNode,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.white : null,
      filled: focusNode.hasFocus ? true : null,
    ),
  )
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for textformfield inside bottom sheet.

Comment: Question doesn't indicate placement on bottom sheet , you need to use  `StatefulBuilder` in that case